# Box inside background image HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a project in college. I have a problem, I have an image that I want to place a box over. It also should have padding on all the sides based on the outline of the image. I have tried all sorts but failed. Could anyone give an example of HTML and CSS to help me with this problem.

[image: This is what it should look like (the grass is the background image)]

Comment: To get the best feedback, post the code you've tried, explain what you would like to happen, and explain what is happening.  Then people will be able to point you in the right direction.  Try to refrain from "Here is what I want.  Please write the code for me" kinds of posts.

Comment: Sorry, I will do in the future this was just the only image I had the other files such as CSS and HTML I would have included if I had access to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the image to a div as a background image, and center the inner div within that using padding.

```
.inner {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

.background {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/800x600');
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4yfju8d/

Comment: don't encourage "do my job for me" questions.

Comment: @MarcB if OP hadn't specified a "college project" no one would take any issue to this question. I operated under the assumption that this was just one individual component to a larger project.

Comment: then it's still "homework", and OP needs to show at least SOME attempt at programming,a nd not just a basica ability to use photoshop.

Comment: I have used a fair amount of CSS and HTML but just couldn't find the answer. Thought stackoverflow was the place for asking these questions that's all. I am perfectly capable of doing my own homework just needed some help. Just as J4G said this is a larger project containing over 10 pages with JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use image as "background: url(...)" of first div, in first div insert second div with paddings "padding: 25px" (for example). Or maybe i wrong understand you)